# Issue with the norm of a vector

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

Consider two vectors `v1 = 1/Sqrt[2] {{Exp[I y/2]}, {Exp[-I y/2]}};` and `v2 = I/Sqrt[2] {{Exp[-I y/2]}, {-Exp[I y/2]}};`, such that  `u = FullSimplify[n (v1 - v2)]`, with `n` a normalization constant. Now, in this case, the dual of `u` is not simple `ConjugateTranspose[u]`, but is defined as `udual = Transpose[A.B.Conjugate[u]];` with `A = 1/Cos[y] ( { {I Sin[y], 1}, {1, -I Sin[y]} } ); B = PauliMatrix[1];` where `y` is real.

Now `FullSimplify[udual.u, {Element[y, Reals]}]` leads to `2 n Conjugate[n] Cos[y]` which immediately tells us that $n=1/\sqrt{2 \cos y}$ is the normalization constant. So let's now define our normalized vector and its dual as

```
unorm = FullSimplify[1/Sqrt[2 Cos[y]] (v1 - v2)];
udualnorm = Transpose[A.B.Conjugate[unorm]];
```

Now I expect `udualnorm .unorm` to be 1, but it is equal to $1/{\rm sign}[\cos y]$. What is going wrong here?

---

All code in one block for ease of copy/paste:

```
v1 = 1/Sqrt[2] {{Exp[I y/2]}, {Exp[-I y/2]}};
v2 = I/Sqrt[2] {{Exp[-I y/2]}, {-Exp[I y/2]}};

u = FullSimplify[n (v1 - v2)]

A = 1/Cos[y] ( {{I Sin[y], 1}, {1, -I Sin[y]}});
B = PauliMatrix[1];
udual = Transpose[A.B.Conjugate[u]];

FullSimplify[udual.u, {Element[y, Reals]}]
(* Out: 2 n Conjugate[n] Cos[y] *)

unorm = FullSimplify[1/Sqrt[2 Cos[y]] (v1 - v2)];
udualnorm = Transpose[A.B.Conjugate[unorm]];

udualnorm . unorm
```

Comment: Although these won't answer your question directly, here are a few comments. Mathematica does not distinguish between column and row vectors, so you can drop one layer of braces in the definitions of `v1` and `v2`: `v1 = 1/Sqrt[2] {Exp[I y/2], Exp[-I y/2]}; v2 = I/Sqrt[2] {Exp[-I y/2], -Exp[I y/2]};` and get the same results. Second, you may have forgotten to mention that you must have used Simplify or `FullSimplify[udualnorm, Element[y, Reals]]` to transform your final result to `1/Sign[Cos[y]]`.

Comment: @MarcoB, thanks for the comments. You are right, I used FullSimplify to arrive at that expression.  If you known someone who can answer, please share the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
udualnorm = Refine[Transpose[A . B . Conjugate[unorm]], _Symbol ∈ Reals]
PowerExpand@FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[udualnorm . unorm]]
(*{{1}}*)
```

Comment: thank. What does _Symbol do here?

Comment: Match the pattern that the symbols in your expression are real numbers (Note that `Head[y]===Symbol`). In this case, the symbol is just the letter `y`, but it's useful to do this when you're working with more symbols. For example, if you calculate `Norm[{a, b}]` you get `Sqrt[Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2]`, but if you add the assumption `Refine[Norm[{a, b}], _Symbol \[Element] Reals]` you get `Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]`.

Answer (score 1):

OP makes a calculation (many details of which are not relevant) involving a nonzero complex number `n`, and a real number `y`. The result of the calculation is

```
2 n Conjugate[n] Cos[y]
```

OP wants to set this expression equal to `1`. The problem is that this is not possible when `Cos[y]` is negative, because `n Conjugate[n] > 0` for every nonzero complex `n`.

With the intention of making the above expression equal to `1`, OP then makes the following

```
choice = n->1/Sqrt[2 Cos[y]]
```

This will be real for some `y` and imaginary for some other `y` (let us assume that `Cos[y]` is not zero) and we get

```
2 n Conjugate[n] /. choice // FullSimplify
(* 1/Abs[Cos[y]] *)
```

Note the `Abs`, which must be there, because `n Conjugate[n] > 0` always. Therefore

```
2 n Conjugate[n] Cos[y] /. choice //FullSimplify
(* Sign[Cos[y]] *)
```

meaning the result $+1$ when $\cos y$ is positive, as OP wants, but it is $-1$ when $\cos y$ is negative, which makes perfect sense. See [`Sign`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sign.html).